# Android Alert Message Need Mandatory Input

Tags: java, android, android-activity, java-native-interface, android-service

I have developed an Android Service which will run in the background. The Service want to accept Yes or No confirmation from the user at an event(say when receive an SMS).
Its working fine; the Yes or No question will be shown to user. But i want the input from (press YES or NO) user without exit from the alert(exit by press on the Mobile Back button or Home button etc).
Please help me how it can be possible.
Below the code I am using;

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
//ctx is the Context
            builder.setTitle("Emergency!"); 
            String txt="Do you want to accept?"; 
            builder.setMessage(txt);
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //Do something 
                }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ///dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this in you AlertDialog

```
 builder.setCancelable(false);
```

hope you are useing `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable back press while the dialog is shown (or possibly, send a "No" response when back button is pressed) with `dialog.setOnKeyListener`

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() { 
  @Override 
  public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      finish();
      dialog.dismiss(); 
    }
    return true; 
  } 
 });
```

Unfortunately you can't override Home button press on Android. You can, however, react to an activity being sent to the background via Home button by implementing `onUserLeaveHint` in the activity hosting your dialog.

Edit: You may also want to disable dismissing the dialog by touching outside (which is the default behavior) by doing

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```